# fill columns of dataframe with groups python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe
which has 1 row

```
key
1
2
3
...
93
```

and i am having `no. of machines = 3`

i want to allocate equal no. of keys to each machine. i.e

there are 9 keys and 3 machines, so, 3 keys should be associated with each machine.
below is the required dataframe:

```
key    machine allocated    
1         1                 
2         1                 
3         1                 
..........

90        3
91        1
92        1
93        1
```

can we do it using groupby ?

Comment: You have a pandas dataframe which has 1 _column_ , right?

Comment: @Mihai-DanielVirna this is just a test example, it might have multiple columns

Comment: Yes, but you wrote _row_ instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use floor division of `arange`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key' : range(1, 10)})

N = 3
N1 = len(df.index) / N

df['machine allocated'] = ((np.arange(len(df.index)) // N1) + 1).astype(int)
print (df)
   key  machine allocated
0    1                  1
1    2                  1
2    3                  1
3    4                  2
4    5                  2
5    6                  2
6    7                  3
7    8                  3
8    9                  3
```

---

```
N = 2
N1 = len(df.index) / N

df['machine allocated'] = ((np.arange(len(df.index)) // N1) + 1).astype(int)
print (df)
   key  machine allocated
0    1                  1
1    2                  1
2    3                  1
3    4                  1
4    5                  1
5    6                  2
6    7                  2
7    8                  2
8    9                  2
```

Comment: sir, actually there was a typing error, i have 90 keys to be distributed equally among 3 machines, please check edit

Comment: if i am having 93 keys, and 6 machines, it is giving machine allocated as 7 for key=91,92,93, it should again revert back to 1,2....3 as per my key increases

Comment: Soory, I was not here. So if `N = 4` with `df = pd.DataFrame({'key' : range(1, 10)})` what is desired output?